# Regular expression that validates only alphabetical characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function:

```
function validate(str1,str2,str3){
  var alph=/^[A-Za-zÑñ]*$/;

  if((str1.match(alph) || str2.match(alph) || str3.match(alph))){
    return true;    
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

If I enter any alphabetical character in my input text it returns true. BUT, when I put any number, it returns true too.

I need to accept only alphabetical characters and spaces, nothing more.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that the conditional expression consists of `||` OR. Is that what you want?

Comment: The function returns true if at least one of the three strings validates. Is that intended?

Comment: Otherwise you could use one concatenated string and validate that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function is supposed to return `false` if *any* strings passed are invalid you need a logical AND:

```
return str1.match(alph) && str2.match(alph) && str3.match(alph);
```

Also, you could use `alph.test()` instead if you're not using the matching results:

```
return alph.test(str1) && alph.test(str2) && alph.test(str3);
```

Comment: It works when I use test method and regex ^[A-Za-z\s]*$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if((str1.match(alph) && str2.match(alph) && str3.match(alph)))
```

Comment: I try this and it returns false

Comment: Sure, this is the correct condition. Using test method works perfect. Thanks!